# Передача переменных между функциями javascript

Tags: функции, переменные, javascript

Например две функции:

```
var func1 = function(var1, var2,..., varN) {
    var first  = var1 + var2;
    var second = first + varN;
    ....
}

var func2 = function() {
}
```

как-то можно передать переменные, например first во вторую функцию не объявляя её глобальной?

Comment: можно еще callback создать например

    var func1 = function(var1,var2,...,callback){// здесь всякие функции callback(first);}

И потом:

    var func2 = function(){func1(var1,var2,...,function(data){//всякие коды моды связанной с var first})}

это в добавок к @Volt )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант так:

```
var func1 = function(var1, var2,..., varN) {
    var first  = var1 + var2;
    var second = first + varN;
    ....
    return first;
}

var func2 = function(getFirst) {
    var first = getFirst(var1, var2,..., varN);
}
```

Вообще, функция должна что-то принимать и что-то возвращать. Лучше будет даже так:

```
var func1 = function (args) {var first; .....; return first},
func2 = function (first)) {};

func1(func1(args));
```

Во избежания такой некрасивой вложенности лучше использовать временные переменные:

```
var func1 = ....,
func2 = ......,
first = func1(args);
func2(first)
```

Comment: есть еще другие способы кроме объявления глобальной переменной? Даже так - есть способ передачи переменной только по конкретному вызову? Например если в first передаются какие-либо персональные данные пользователя?

Comment: Не понял. В javascript нету типа данных "персональные данные пользователя". Объясните на примере что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: хочу передать данные, которые должны быть доступны только зарегистрированным пользователям.

Comment: Псевдокод на сервере: if (user.isAuthored) send(secretData) else send(publicData)
При чем тут клиент?

Comment: Да насколько я понимаю передавать в JS какие-то критичные данные не есть хорошо. Наверно вопрос про максимально безопасный вариант здесь отпадает.

Comment: вопрос по последнему примеру вашему: first = func1(args); Аргументы для функции нужно указывать только те, которые есть в окружении вызова? То есть если я делаю вызов внутри другой функции которая не располагает данными для приведения в качестве аргументов, то я их и не задам?

Comment: "Аргументы для функции нужно указывать только те, которые есть в окружении вызова?" Да. "То есть если я делаю вызов внутри другой функции которая не располагает данными для приведения в качестве аргументов, то я их и не задам?" Если "другая" функция "видит" переменные, которые надо передать, то вы их и передадите. Если не видит, то и не передадите.

Answer (score 5):

Например:
 Вернуть переменную из одной функции, получить во второй:

```
 function f1(){
    var trololo = 345;
    return trololo;
 }
 function f2(){
    var myTrololo = f1();
 }
```

Объявить вторую функцию внутри первой  :

```
    function f1(){
       var trololo = 345;
       function f2(){
         var myTrololo = trololo;
       }
    }
```

Использовать для связи какой-нибудь объект, к которому будут иметь доступ обе функции:

```
var GodObj = {};
function f1(){
   var trololo = 345;
   GodObj.lala = trololo;
}

function f2(){
   var myTrololo = GodObj.lala;
}
```

Собственно вызвать вторую функцию из первой, с некоторым обычно необязательным параметром, но конечно тут зависит от того что эта функция делает

```
function f1(){
     var trololo = 345;
     f2(trololo);
}

functin f2(trololo){
     if(typeof(trololo)!='undefined') myTrololo = trololo;// Если такой параметр есть
}
```

Comment: Второй метод вряд ли ему поможет, потому что f2 будет не видна снаружи f1. Но знать об этом способе тоже надо.

Comment: @alexandrr, мало ли, конкретная задача непонятна, может и так пригодится)

Comment: на самом деле сейчас сяду и попробую вариант от alexandrr, но думаю для поиска будет интересно так как за пол дня я много чего прочитал, однако только и разговор про глобальные переменные, еще про куки иногда упоминалось. Так что думаю это полезно будет очень многим.

Comment: @kils, о да, можно еще через куки, localStorage, sessionStorage, через сервер можно... Тут все зависит от конкретной задачи

Comment: Мне бы так, чтобы посторонний пользователь не смог манипулировать этими данными. Через сессии вроде нельзя передать на js без применения дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: @kils. Посторонний пользователь - это кто? Очень важно чтобы вы понимали от кого именно хотите защитить данные.
А sessionStorage - это работа с браузерной сессией а не серверной.

Comment: @kils https может надо?

Comment: @alexandrr, против mim - безусловно надо. Вот только пока не понятно, от кого хотят защитить)

Comment: @alexandrr функция из которой я хочу вытащить переменную и сама эта переменная является данными из JSON, в свою очередь который передается php из базы и содержит все данные из БД по конкретной тематике (например список всех сотрудников), но функция выполняется при загрузке раздела (например того же списка сотрудников) независимо от того вошел авторизованный пользователь или нет, но данные никуда не передает, а если сделаю глобальную переменную то данные буду в ней. С другой стороны раз функцию уже грузит данные то они уже могут быть доступны. но всеже